# Unique ID Validation Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am writing a statement which checks my database to see if a value exists so that it does not insert a record to the database if it has the same unique ID. I have my exceptions working for the rest of my fields however I am having trouble retrieving data from the database to compare to the value I have caught from the database. Below is an example of my code.

```
int EmployeeIDCatched = int.Parse(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
var EmployeeIDQuery = from EmployeeID in EmployeeDataSet.Employee select EmployeeIDCatched;
if (EmployeeIDQuery.Equals(EmployeeIDCatched))
```

I was rather hoping someone might be able to correct this for me.

The dataset is called `EmployeeDataSet`, the table is called Employee and the row I am searching is called `EmployeeID`

If anyone could help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want only one hit and you want the employee-object returned:

```
int employeeIDCatched = int.Parse(employeeIDTextBox.Text);

var matchingEmployee = (from employee in EmployeeDataSet.Employee
                        where employee.ID.Equals(employeeIDCatched)
                        select employee).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update**: Not sure if I didn't read the question close enough or if the detail changed, but here is now to just get a `bool`-result:

```
int employeeIDCatched = int.Parse(employeeIDTextBox.Text);

bool hasMatchingEmployee = EmployeeDataSet.Employee.Any(employee =>
    employee.ID.Equals(employeeIDCatched));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I have only one more problem though. The following piece of code has either stopped working or did not work in the first place.

if (EmployeeIDQuery.Equals(EmployeeIDCatched))

{

ErrorList.Add("The unique ID is taken");
Valid = false;
}

Comment: Since I don't know the type of `EmployeeIDQuery` it's impossible for me to know what the `Equals`-method does. But post this problem to another Stackoverflow-question and provide the error-message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Any` method to check if a row exists.

```
var selectedEmployeeId = int.Parse(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
if (EmployeeDataSet.Employee.Any(e => e.EmployeeID == selectedEmployeeId))
```